# Javascript array to PHP to database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How to pass an array from javascript to controller using codeigniter

Here is my code:

view:

```
function submitFunc(){
  var arrayName = ['John ' , 'Josh' , 'Steph'];
  var arraySerial = [ 123, 456 , 789];

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  data: {arrayName:arrayName, arraySerial: arraySerial }, //not sure of this code
  url: '<?= base_url()."mycontroller/insertData"?>',
  success: function(data){
  }
  });
}
```

and in my controller:

```
    public function insertData()
      {
          $data = array(
              'Name' =>$this->input->post('arrayName'),
              'Serial' =>$this->input->post('arraySerial '),
          );
          $this->db->insert('test',$data);
      }
```

trying to achieve something like this n database:

```
| Name  | Serial|
| John  |   1   |
| Josh  |   2   |
| Steph |   3   |
```

Comment: What happend when you ran this code? You don't report of any *problem*...

Comment: This tutorial might be able to help your: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the data in json format and then send it to controller

```
     function submitFunc(){
      var arrayName = ['John ' , 'Josh' , 'Steph'];
      var jsonName = JSON.stringify(arrayName);
      var arraySerial = [ 123, 456 , 789];
      var jsonSerial = JSON.stringify(arraySerial);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: {arrayName:jsonName, arraySerial: jsonSerial }, //not sure of this code
      url: '<?= base_url()."mycontroller/insertData"?>',
      success: function(data){
      }
      });
    }
```

In you controller

```
  public function insertData()
  {
      $arrayName = $this->input->post('arrayName');
      $decodeName= json_decode($arrayName,true); // will return an array
      $arraySerial = $this->input->post('arraySerial ');
      $decodeSerial =  json_decode($arraySerial ,true); // will return an array
      for($i=0;$i<=count($decodeName);$i++){
      $data[] = array('Name'=>$decodeName[$i],'Serial'=>$decodeSerial[$i]);
      }

      $this->load->modelName($data);        
  }
```

in your model

```
 public function modelName($data){
  $this->db->insert_batch('tablename', $data);
 }
```

Comment: @StornFrial My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following controller code to insert data:

```
$arrayName = $this->input->post('arrayName');
$Serial = $this->input->post('arraySerial');
$data = array();
foreach($arrayName as $key=>$name){
    $data[] = array('Name'=>$name,'Serial'=>$Serial[$key]);
}

$this->db->insert_batch('test', $data);
```